# NSFetchedResultsController and child UITableViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

Right now I have an `UITableViewController` that displays a set of `Artist` objects sorted into sections (alphabetically) using `NSFetchedResultsController`. When you tap an artist in that list, a second `UITableViewController` is pushed and displays the `artist.shows` objects, also sorted into sections (by date).

Right now I'm sorting that second data source (artist.shows) "manually", using `NSSortDescriptor` and a `for()` loop to determine where to have the table view sections (one section for every month).

Is that the right way to go? Would it make more sense to create a second `NSFetchedResultsController` to sort that data, although it would basically be fetching data I already have in `artist.shows`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should definitely use a second fetched results controller. It can share the managedObjectContext with the first, allowing to access the already faulted objects in that context.

You'll want to structure your predicate / sort descriptor for the controller appropriately, such as:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"artist.name == %@" argumentsArray:[NSArray arrayWithObject:selectedArtist.name]];
```

You could also scope it by the actual artist object but that should give you the idea.